# How to get old text after changing by substring?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here I am trying to display each div text .But if div text will greater 190 words do cut words and show only 190 words with `read more` link.I have trouble in display old full text when click `read more` link.Don't know how to store relevant old full text and re-show in popup style.

```
<style type="text/css">
div{
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  background: #faaaaf;  
  border : 2px solid #aedd87;
  position: relative;  
}
.popup{
  position:absolute;top:20%;left:25%;border:1px solid red;background:#f39323;width:50%;height:50%;
}
.close{
  top: -5;
  left: 98%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 10%;
  background: brown;
  position: absolute;
}
</style>
<div>Accelerator beam data commissioning equipment and procedures:
Report of the TG-106 of the Therapy Physics Committee of the AAPM
Indra J. Dasa
Department of Radiation Oncology, University of Pennsylvania, Philadelphia, Pennsylvania 19104
Chee-Wai Cheng</div>
<div>Accelerator beam data commissioning equipment and procedures:
Report of the TG-106 of the Therapy Physics Committee of the AAPM
Indra J. Dasa
Department of Radiation Oncology, University of Pennsylvania, Philadelphia, Pennsylvania 19104
Chee-Wai Cheng
</div>
<div>Accelerator beam data commissioning equipment and procedures:
Report of the TG-106 of the Therapy Physics Committee of the AAPM
Indra J. Dasa
Department of Radiation Oncology, University of Pennsylvania, Philadelphia, Pennsylvania 19104
</div>
```

This is what I tried by jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('div').each(function(i){
    fulltext = $(this).text();
    if(fulltext.length > 190){      
     $(this).text(fulltext.substring(0,190)).append("<a href='#' class='read'>Read More</a>");
    }  
  });
  $('.read').click(function(){
    //stuck here getting old full text
     var popup = "<div class='popup'><span class='close'>X</span>"+$(this).parent().text()+"</div>";         $('body').append(popup);
  });
  $('body').on('click','.close',function(){
    $('.popup').remove();
  });
</script>
```

In `$('.read').click()` ,how can i access old full text and display in popup box ???

Comment: You do realize that fulltext.length > 190 is checking the number of characters not words right?

Comment: @JoelsElf yes my misspelling ! I mean characters !!

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem in your code is that you have to assign the click event for the .read elements after these elements are created.

```
    $('div').each(function(i){
      var fulltext = $(this).text();

      if(fulltext.length > 190) { 

        $(this).text(fulltext.substring(0,190)).append("<a href='#' class='read'>Read More</a>");
      }

      $('.read').click(function(){
        //stuck here getting old full text
         var popup = "<div class='popup'><span class='close'>X</span>"+$(this).parent().text()+"</div>";         $('body').append(popup);
  });
    });
```

Have a look at this code:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jruizx/p5ne00c7/5/)

I realise that the popup just show the same text, I have modified the code to save the previous text as attribute, so the popup can show the long text.

Comment: This is the correct answer (up vote). I forked the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lkqw2t26/2/) and fixed the css for the .popup and .close to make the text more legible.